# How to clean up angular cache between tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am working in angularjs, and my unit tests use Jasmine and mgMock.

I learned that when i have tests that change the provider object of a certain service (like configuration), those changes are carried over to other tests in the same run. This creates run dependency between the tests.

Does anyone know how i can clear the angular provider & instance cache after each test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my code:

my code was similar to the code below. And since angular keeps the module definitions between test runs (as it should since it is not responsible for script loading), the status variable was shared between tests.

```
(function(){
  angular.module('myModule',['ng']).provider(myServiceProvider);

  var status = 'init';

  function setStatus(newStatus) {
    status = newStatus;
  }

  function myServiceProvider() {
    function myServiceFactory() {
      return status;
    }

    return {
      $get: myServiceFactory,
      setStatus: setStatus
    };
  }
})();
```

the solution was to make sure that the variable was declared inside the provider creation scope:

```
(function(){
  angular.module('myModule',['ng']).provider(myServiceProvider);

  function myServiceProvider() {
    var status = 'init';

    function setStatus(newStatus) {
      status = newStatus;
    }

    function myServiceFactory() {
      return status;
    }

    return {
      $get: myServiceFactory,
      setStatus: setStatus
    };
  }
})();
```